# Can't connect to test database with Docker and Laravel Sail

Tags: laravel, docker, phpunit

I'm trying to set up my first test database using Laravel's sail.  I can see that the test database is created and a user is added:

```
mysql_test_1    | 2021-03-13 20:20:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating database test_database
mysql_test_1    | 2021-03-13 20:20:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Creating user test_root
mysql_test_1    | 2021-03-13 20:20:32+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Giving user test_root access to schema test_database
```

However, when I try to connect via TablePlus, I get:

> Access denied for user 'test_root'@'172.24.0.1' (using password: YES)
>
> Host: 127.0.0.1   Port: 3306   User: test_root   Password: test_root
> Database: test_database

My .env has the following:

```
TEST_DB_CONNECTION=mysql
TEST_DB_HOST=mysql_test
TEST_DB_PORT=3306
TEST_DB_DATABASE=test_database
TEST_DB_USERNAME=test_root
TEST_DB_PASSWORD=test_root
```

and my docker-compose.yml file has:

```
mysql:
    image: 'mysql:8.0'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
        - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
    networks:
        - sail
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping"]
mysql_test:
  image: "mysql:8.0"
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${TEST_DB_PASSWORD}"
    MYSQL_DATABASE: "${TEST_DB_DATABASE}"
    MYSQL_USER: "${TEST_DB_USERNAME}"
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${TEST_DB_PASSWORD}"
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
  networks:
    - sail
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are launching two different mysql containers :

- `mysql` is running and linking its 3306 port with your computer 3306 port. You can connect to it using the host `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`. It is this dbms that gives you the 'Access Denied' error.
- `mysql_test` is running but its 3306 port is not linked to any port on your host, meaning you cannot directly access it.

Since you seem to be running TablePlus from your host (and not from a docker container), I'd suggest to link the port 3307 *(or any other port)* from your host to the port 3306 of your container, using the "ports" option like you did for your first container.
Then, configure TablePlus so that it connects to your first dbms on port 3306 and your second dbms on port 3307.

Comment: I tried your advice and am getting "Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql_test' (0)".  Any other thoughts?

Comment: In your docker compose, is your service called `mysql_test` ? Also, are you running TablePlus in a container ?

Comment: I've added my docker-compose file for more information.  I'm not sure how to tell if TablePlus is run in a container.  But, if it helps, I'm able to connect to my non-test database in TablePlus.  (For that one, I'm using 127.0.0.1 as my host)

Comment: Yes, my apologies for the delayed response!  I'm still not able to run my test because the database can't be found.  However, it feels like a separate issue, so I'm going to remove that part of my question and mark this as correct.