# Test database not found using Laravel sail

Tags: laravel, docker, phpunit

I'm using Laravel Sail for the first time and can connect to my database, as well as connect to the test database using TablePlus after [changing ports](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66618511/cant-connect-to-test-database-with-docker-and-laravel-sail/66618578) with credentials Host: 127.0.0.1, Port: 3307, User: test_root, Password: test_root.  However, when I run

```
sail test --testsuite Feature --filter=LoginAsTest
```

I get:

> SQLSTATE[HY000] [1049] Unknown database 'test_database' (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

In my .env file I have:

```
TEST_DB_CONNECTION=mysql
TEST_DB_HOST=mysql_test
TEST_DB_PORT=3306
TEST_DB_DATABASE=test_database
TEST_DB_USERNAME=test_root
TEST_DB_PASSWORD=test_root
```

and my docker-compose.yml has:

```
mysql:
    image: 'mysql:8.0'
    ports:
        - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3306}:3306'
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_DATABASE: '${DB_DATABASE}'
        MYSQL_USER: '${DB_USERNAME}'
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: '${DB_PASSWORD}'
        MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
    volumes:
        - 'sailmysql:/var/lib/mysql'
    networks:
        - sail
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping"]
mysql_test:
  image: "mysql:8.0"
  ports:
    - '${FORWARD_DB_PORT:-3307}:3306'
  environment:
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "${TEST_DB_PASSWORD}"
    MYSQL_DATABASE: "${TEST_DB_DATABASE}"
    MYSQL_USER: "${TEST_DB_USERNAME}"
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: "${TEST_DB_PASSWORD}"
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "yes"
  networks:
    - sail
```

Any thoughts as to why I can connect via TablePlus, but not my application?

Update: I've also added:

```
'mysql_test' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
            'port' => env('TEST_DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('TEST_DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
            'username' => env('TEST_DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
            'password' => env('TEST_DB_PASSWORD', ''),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
            'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
                PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
            ]) : [],
        ],
```

to my config/database.php

and in my phpunit.xml I have:

```
 <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql_test"/>
 <env name="DB_DATABASE" value="test_database"/>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure your `TEST_DB_PORT` should be `3307` in your `.env`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The docker containers on macOS are running inside a virtual machine that is created by docker-for-mac and the traffic is routed trough the network interface of the virtual machine.

As described in the [docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#there-is-no-docker0-bridge-on-macos) there is no bridge between the macOS and the docker-engine. As consequence, although the `docker ps` will show the port is published, the container will not be accessible on the `localhost` of macOS, unless explicitly published on `0.0.0.0`.

The difference between the network subsystem of docker running on linux and on macOS is described in this [post](https://biancatamayo.me/blog/docker-troubleshooting-macos-network/).

To connect to the containers, easiest way is to use the public IP of the machine, so in your case:

1. Find the IP of of your machine as described in [SO](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/20547/how-do-i-find-my-ip-address-from-the-command-line)

   ```
   ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -Fv 127.0.0.1 | awk '{print $2}'
   ```
2. Change the connection string to

   ```
   'host' => env('DB_HOST', '<<your ip address>>'),
   'port' => env('TEST_DB_PORT', '3307'),
   ```

Comment: I've tried the above and I get the same error.  As another check, I've tried sail mysql and then SHOW DATABASES; and the test database isn't appearing.

Comment: @Eric in which container are you running the sail and from where are you testing? What is the error you get from sail?

Comment: (Noob here) I'm not sure what you mean which container.  And, I'm running sail test with the error " SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')"

Comment: where are you running sail? Are you running it in a container or on your host?

Comment: I think my host?  I'm just typing sail mysql from the command line; when I do sail mysql, the non-test database appears when I type SHOW databases; if that helps.  It's just the test one that isn't appearing even though I can connect via TablePlus.

Comment: ok, you error `Connection refused` means you have either the `host` or the `port` wrong. I need to know where are you running to help you set proper host and port. There is difference if you are running from a container (which was my assumption and my answer), if you run from the host, and if you run from another host. So find out and update the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229895/discussion-between-eric-and-jordanvrtanoski).